# Html 5 datepicker in firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way that I can set enable a datepicker in firefox(version 21) with HTML 5. I dont want to use a jQuery based datepicker because javascript will be disabled in the browsers where the website will be used. The datepicker works fine with Chrome.

So if html 5 datepicker is not supported,how can I add a datepicker without jquery ?

Comment: Install Firebug and see what console shows. Maybe you get an error.

Comment: If a datepicker isn't built into the browser, you have to add your own using JavaScript. I'm not sure what other solution you think might exist. [Here's one good approach that uses Modernizr to load jQuery-UI's datepicker only when it's needed](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/).

Comment: Almost two years and more than fifteen versions of Firefox later, no support for date and time input types in sight. This is... upsetting. But who cares about date picking when they have a Firefox OS to thrive on, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

jQuery UI has a datepicker widget that you can conditionally load if the browser doesn't have one built in. The catch is that even if [you *only* select the datepicker widget in a custom jQuery UI build](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000), it's still a significant download.

My favorite solution is to use yepnope, which comes with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-inputtypes-shiv-cssclasses-load), to conditionally load the jQuery UI CSS and JS files *only if* needed for the datepicker. By combining this with an [optimized build of Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-inputtypes-shiv-cssclasses-load) and [a datepicker-only jQuery UI build](http://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.10.3&components=1000000000001000000000000000000000), it gives you the smallest download for all possible browsers.

```
yepnope({ /* included with Modernizr */
  test : Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
  nope : {
    'css': '/path-to-your-css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',
    'js': '/path-to-your-js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.datepicker.min.js'
  },
  callback: { // executed once files are loaded
    'js': function() { $('input[type=date]').datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}); } // default HTML5 format
  }
});
```

Comment: now that ```yepnope``` is deprecated, I adapted the solution indicated in
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34518146/1960071.

Comment: @j4v1 By all means, post it here as a new answer!

Answer (score 13):

Firefox 57 (Nov 14, 2017) supports it:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: So if html 5 datepicker is not supported then how can i add a datepicker(without jquery)

Comment: If you can't use javascript, I don't know a way. Maybe you can use a text input and validate the date in the backend.

Comment: As of May 16, 2014 the datepicker (<input type="date" />) is not supported by IE nor FF. I didn't check safari, but in chrome it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I found this here (firefox 54), at least, which gives hope:

Go to about:config and search for 
dom.forms.datetime

Set both entries found to true, et voilà!
Now all they need to do is enable them by default!

Answer (score 2):

Firefox 57 finally has a datepicker with a clickable calender (<input type="date">).

[image]

The timepicker is just a text field that limits input to valid times. Sadly, it only supports 12 hour time format (<input type="time">).

[image]

datetime-local still isn't supported (<input type="datetime-local">).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox (version 21) doesn't support `input type=date`.

Here you have a site that tells you what it supports and what it doesn't [Firefox21](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ff21.html)

Comment: Firefox 34 still does not support input type=date.
Are they going to ever comply with the HTML5 recommendation?

Comment: And now Firefox 35 same disappointment. Time for me to donate to Firefox, I can't stand to see them falling behind other browsers.

Comment: Agreed... amazing that Firefox has not been able to keep up with these HTML5 controls.

Comment: Firefox 47, still nothing. Abandon all hope, ye who use Firefox.

Comment: and FF 49...too

Comment: 50 checking in here. This is hilariously still not working. I mean just how difficult could it possibly be.

Comment: 53... Nope, still not implemented

Comment: Almost 4 years after this post and we are still waiting. Perhaps they are waiting for HTML6.