# Modernizr.load Deprecated. Yepnope.js Deprecated. Now what?

Tags: conditional-statements, modernizr, yepnope

Prior to Modernizr v3, I was using yepnope.js

Modernizr.load and yepnope.js have both been deprecated. How do we conditionally call stylesheets or javascript files now?

Example that worked with Modernizr v2.5.3:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr['object-fit'],
  nope: ['./dist/scripts/object-fit.js'],
  complete: function(){
  if (!Modernizr['object-fit']) {
   jQuery(".poster img").imageScale({
   scale: "best-fill", 
   rescaleOnResize: true
   });
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a new syntax](https://modernizr.com/docs#using-modernizr-with-javascript) and the feature names are all lowercase. You can combine that with [jQuery's getScript method](https://davidwalsh.name/loading-scripts-jquery).

Which would look something like this:

```
if (Modernizr.objectfit){
    jQuery.getScript("./dist/scripts/object-fit.js")
        //it worked! do something!
        .done(function(){
            console.log('js loaded');
        })
        //it didn't work! do something!
        .fail(function(){
            console.log('js not loaded');
        });
} else {
    jQuery(".poster img").imageScale({
        scale: "best-fill", 
        rescaleOnResize: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @mhk! Sorry, it took so long to reply.

Comment: To clarify, this is what worked for me: 

```
$(function(){
if (Modernizr.objectfit){
} else {
$.getScript("./dist/scripts/object-fit.js", function() {
$(".img-scale").imageScale({
scale: "best-fill", 
rescaleOnResize: true
});
});
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719185 — no jQuery required. (Note that there's a shorter Promise example a bit down in the answer; don't stop reading after the first example (like I did)).

And here for CSS: `loadCSS`: https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/src/loadCSS.js

— this is, in a way, even better than YepNope.js, if you don't need any of its features except for just loading stuff + callback. Because the stuff linked above, is smaller (smaller `min.js.gz`) than yepnope.js.

(And can combine with `Modernizr` like `mhk` showed in his answer.)