# Why datepicker not working in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

My Javascript code is like this :

```
$('#idTourDateDetails').datepicker({
      monthNames: [ "Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Agustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember" ],
            dayNames: [ "Minggu", "Senin", "Selasa", "Rabu", "Kamis", "Jumat", "Sabtu" ],
            dayNamesMin: [ "M", "S", "S", "R", "K", "J", "S" ],
//                        showOn: 'both',
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            inline: true,
            yearRange: '-100:-12',
            defaultDate: '1916-01-01'
 });
```

Demo and complete code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/93eTU/1751/

When I using firefox browser and select year in year combobox, it's not working. Year did not appear. But when I using chrome browser and select year in year combobox, it's working. Year appear

Why year not display in firefox browser?

Any solution to solve my problem

Thank you

Comment: I think your question answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292910/html-5-datepicker-in-firefox

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887850/jquery-ui-datepicker-month-year-dropdown-is-not-working-in-popup-in-latest-firef

Comment: i tried it in ff its is working what is you ff version?maybe it has something to do with version